# "No more backup pools left. Using primary and starting over."

Tags: json-rpc, solo-mining, gpu-mining, miner-configuration, poclbm

I am not using a pool, I am using my graphics cards mining with poclbm over rpc. i do not understand why I get these messages.

```
localhost:8332 15/08/2012 22:40:13, No more backup pools left. Using primary and starting over.
localhost:8332 15/08/2012 22:40:13, Setting server (MYUSERNAME @ localhost:8332)
localhost:8332 16/08/2012 13:15:35, No more backup pools left. Using primary and starting over.
localhost:8332 16/08/2012 13:15:35, Setting server (MYUSERNAME @ localhost:8332)
```

Is this something that is fixable? Should I bother (does it affect the mining in any significant way)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you have no backup pool configured. So if your server doesn't respond quickly enough, poclbm just fails over back to the primary pool. If these are only happening occasionally, I wouldn't worry about it. Anything that momentarily prevents the RPC call from getting a response can do this.