# Broken miner: no more backup pools

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, gpu, poclbm

I have 3 graphics cards running poclbm each with a rate of about 140 MH/s. This has been running since I posted an earlier question ( ["No more backup pools left. Using primary and starting over."](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4454/no-more-backup-pools-left-using-primary-and-starting-over) ) in August I have not found/created a block in that time.

However every so many hours or every few days (irregularly, but never 5 days uninterrupted), I get the message, "No more backup pools left. Using primary and starting over."

Is this message effecting my ability to mine, or am I just impatient?

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that your miner couldn't get work from the pool fast enough and so some mining power was wasted. If this only happens occasionally, I wouldn't worry about it. If it happens often enough that it's impacting your mining rate, you may wish to configure a backup pool. If it's happening because your Internet connection is slow or unreliable, there's probably nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I am trying to mine solo. What would a backup pool mean in this context?

Comment: It would mean your Bitcoin client wasn't responding fast enough.